# Simple way of making a Mongo Collection mirror a local filesystem

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unix

I just want to serve a MongoDB collection that stays in sync with a directory on the local filesystem. So if I CRUD a Mongo document in the collection, representing a text file in the directory, the filesystem should almost-instantly reflect the changes.

This seems like a common enough use case for development stuff, but obviously with a lot of technical gotchas to handle, and my search skills are failing me.

Im interested in any answers, but especially those involving just Mongo+*nix or Mongo+NodeJS.

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for. What is the connection with the file system?

Comment: In your scenario are you looking to update the database when you modify the file as well? Or is it a one-way relationship? If you only need to propagate changes in the DB to the file system then Aleksey's answer below is what you need. If you also need to propagate changes to the files up to MongoDB then you'll need to get a file watcher module and do the same thing in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good fit: https://npmjs.org/package/mongo-watch. This library will notify you whenever change happens. You can save your document to the file system when event is triggered.